# Convert character vector to numeric vector in R for value assignment?

Tags: r, math, syntax, statistics

I have:

```
z = data.frame(x1=a, x2=b, x3=c, etc)
```

I am trying to do:

```
for (i in 1:10)
{
    paste(c('N'),i,sep="") -> paste(c('z$x'),i,sep="")
}
```

Problems:

1. `paste(c('z$x'),i,sep="")` yields `"z$x1", "z$x1"` instead of calling the actual values. I need the expression to be evaluated. I tried `as.numeric, eval`. Neither seemed to work.
2. `paste(c('N'),i,sep="")` yields `"N1", "N2"`. I need the expression to be merely used as name. If I try to assign it a value such as `paste(c('N'),5,sep="") -> 5`, ie `"N5" -> 5` instead of `N5 -> 5`, I get target of assignment expands to non-language object.

This task is pretty trivial since I can simply do:

N1 = x1...
N2 = x2...

etc, but I want to learn something new

Comment: use `get` and `assign`, but don't do that -- use a list instead.  There's an R FAQ on this, as well as lots of SO questions (now that you know the right things to look for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using something like `for( i in 1:10 ) z[,i] <- N[,i]`...

BUT, since you said you want to learn something new, you can play around with `parse` and `substitute`.

NOTE: these little tools are funny, but experienced users (not me) avoid them.

This is called "computing on the language". It's very interesting, and it helps understanding the way R works. Let me try to give an intro:

The basic language construct is a constant, like a numeric or character vector. It is trivial because it is not different from its "unevaluated" version, but it is one of the building blocks for more complicated expressions.

The (officially) basic language object is the `symbol`, also known as a `name`. It's nothing but a pointer to another object, i.e., a token that identifies another object which may or may not exist. For instance, if you run `x <- 10`, then `x` is a symbol that refers to the value `10`. In other words, evaluating the symbol `x` yields the numeric vector `10`. Evaluating a non-existant symbol yields an error.

A symbol looks like a character string, but it is not. You can turn a string into a symbol with `as.symbol("x")`.

The next language object is the `call`. This is a recursive object, implemented as a `list` whose elements are either constants, symbols, or another calls. The first element must *not* be a constant, because it must evaluate to the real `function` that will be called. The other elements are the arguments to this function.

If the first argument does not evaluate to an existing function, R will throw either `Error: attempt to apply non-function` or `Error: could not find function "x"` (if the first argument is a symbol that is undefined or points to something other than a function).

Example: the code line `f(x, y+z, 2)` will be parsed as a list of 4 elements, the first being `f` (as a symbol), the second being `x` (another symbol), the third another `call`, and the fourth a numeric constant. The third element `y+z`, is just a function with two arguments, so it parses as a list of three names: `'+'`, `y` and `z`.

Finally, there is also the `expression` object, that is a list of calls/symbols/constants, that are meant to be evaluated one by one.

You'll find lots of information here:

https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language

OK, now let's get back to your question :-)

What you have tried does not work because the output of `paste` is a character string, and the assignment function expects as its first argument something that evaluates to a symbol, to be either created or modified. Alternativelly, the first argument can also evaluate to a call associated with a *replacement* function. These are a little trickier, but they are handled by the assignment function itself, not by the parser.

The error message you see, `target of assignment expands to non-language object`, is triggered by the assignment function, precisely because your target evaluates to a string.

We can fix that building up a call that has the symbols you want in the right places. The most "brute force" method is to put everything inside a string and use parse:

```
parse(text=paste('N',i," -> ",'z$x',i,sep=""))
```

Another way to get there is to use `substitute`:

```
substitute(x -> y, list(x=as.symbol(paste("N",i,sep="")), y=substitute(z$w, list(w=paste("x",i,sep="")))))
```

the inner substitute creates the `call`s `z$x1`, `z$x2` etc. The outer substitute puts this call as the taget of the assignment, and the symbols `N1`, `N2` etc as the values.

`parse` results in an `expression`, and `substitute` in a `call`. Both can be passed to `eval` to get the same result.

Just one final note: I repeat that all this is intended as a didactic example, to help understanding the inner workings of the language, but it is *far* from good programming practice to use `parse` and `substitute`, except when there is *really* no alternative.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.frame` is a `named list`.  It usually good practice, and idiomatically `R-ish` not to have lots of objects in the global environment, but to have related (or similar) objects in lists and to use `lapply` etc.

You could use `list2env` to multiassign the named elements of your list (the columns in your data.frame) to the global environment

```
DD <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = letters[1:3], z = 3:1)
list2env(DD, envir = parent.frame())
## <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
## ta da, x, y and z now exist within the global environment 
x
## [1] 1 2 3
y
## [1] a b c
## Levels: a b c
z
## [1] 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. But here is a guess:

```
### Create a data.frame using the alphabet
data <- data.frame(x = 'a', y = 'b', z = 'c')

### Create a numerical index corresponding to the letter position in the alphabet
index <- which(tolower(letters[1:26]) == data[1, ])

### Use an 'lapply' to apply a function to every element in 'index'; creates a list
val <- lapply(index, function(x) {
    paste('N', x, sep = '')
})

### Assign names to our list
names(val) <- names(data)

### Observe the result
val$x
```